# Does Kruskal's algorithm find the minimum bottleneck spanning tree? if so how do we prove correctness?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, kruskals-algorithm

How would you prove Kruskal's algorithm always produces a minimum bottleneck spanning tree?

Comment: That's a well-known algorithm, discussed and disected galore. Didn't you find any discussion of it searching the web?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Somewhat interestingly, Kruskal's and the problem's Wikipedia page don't mention each other. To answer this question, I think googling the problem is more fruitful than googling Kruskal.

Comment: There's a page on the algorithm itself, too.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What do you mean?

Comment: There are separate pages on the person, the algorithm they invented and the problem(s) it solves.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Of course I meant the Kruskal *algorithm* page. It doesn't mention that problem. So what's your point? Or are you saying there's a *third* page, with problems it solves, and that page mentions that problem? I can't find that, please show it then.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Kruskal (person), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_algorithm (algorithm), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree (problem), which is a special case for a minimum spanning forest (another problem) for connected graphs. BTW: If you can get hold of it, Steven Skiena's "Algorithm Design Manual" is _so_ worth reading.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Why are you linking to that problem? That's not what this question is about. It's about [minimum **bottleneck** spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bottleneck_spanning_tree).

Comment: My fault, sorry.